# Fickle people who agree just to annoy

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, pejorative-language

During an argument one person capitulates, not because they agree, but just to irritate the other with phrases like:

*Yes, of course you are right* etc.

Is there a specific word to describe this person?

Comment: Someone who has more important matters to dwell on?

Comment: ......sarcastic

Comment: Martyr? (Not sure it's a good fit because the question doesn't provide enough context.)

Comment: There is a specific word, you're 100% right. Good work.

Comment: @Ronan don't be so patronising.

Comment: Tongue was firmly in cheek there @Neil

Comment: And what a helpful tongue it was Ronan, so kind.

Comment: Do you mean that they intend to irritate? Or simply that agreeing with everything irritates you?

Comment: @Ronan Oh I knew, I just wanted to drop the word 'patronising' into the conversation.

Answer (score 1):

The verb that seems to come closest is **[humor](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/humor#humor)**

> Comply with the wishes of (someone) in order to keep them content, however unreasonable such wishes might be: *she was always humoring him to prevent trouble*

This conveys expression of insincere agreement (or conduct) while actually disagreeing. However, the term is often used to describe a process intended to soothe rather than annoy. If irritation is part of the concept ytou wish to convey, you would probably need an adjective

> She snidely *humored* him, agreeing with his every pronouncement, eventually leading to his storming out of the room.

There is a related concept, **[yes-man](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yes-man)**

> a person who agrees with everything that is said; especially :  one who endorses or supports without criticism every opinion or proposal of an associate or superior

Again, there is often an implication that the process is intended to placate rather than annoy. An adjective could change that

> He was a transparent *yes-man*. His boss found the unbridled enthusiasm annoying, not flattering.